# Extracting public key from private key in OpenSSL

Tags: c++, c, openssl, rsa

I need to extract the RSA public key from a RSA private key using OpenSSL.

I'm currently using `RSAPublicKey_dup()` passing the `RSA*` private key to get the public key. However, while the call seems to work, I cannot load (or use) this public key using the openssl command-line tool.

If I generate the public key using the command-line tool ("`$ openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout > public.pem`"), I can use it and it works like a charm.

Do you guys know how I can get this work ? Maybe another function ? The OpenSSL documentation is quite hard to browse...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make this work using `PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY()` to write the PEM data to a in-memory buffer, then using `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY()` to get a new `RSA*`.

Now the generated public key can be used ;)

Comment: I dont' remember the trick I pulled, gotta see my version history