# iOS/Objective C: Display key pair generated by OpenSSL

Tags: objective-c, ios, encryption, openssl, rsa

I  use openssl for RSA encryption in my iOS application. 
I have to send the publicKey to a SOAP webservice..I'm already able to generate a key pair, en-/decrypt data, but I wonder if there is a way to display the keys on console? 
Anybody know?

Open SSL is written in C..So I get this struct..

```
struct
        {
        BIGNUM *n;              // public modulus
        BIGNUM *e;              // public exponent
        BIGNUM *d;              // private exponent
        BIGNUM *p;              // secret prime factor
        BIGNUM *q;              // secret prime factor
        BIGNUM *dmp1;           // d mod (p-1)
        BIGNUM *dmq1;           // d mod (q-1)
        BIGNUM *iqmp;           // q^-1 mod p
        // ...
        };
 RSA
```

At the [documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rsa.html) i found the function [RSA_print](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_print.html)..But I don't know how to use it right..All my tries failed...:(

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Use `NSLog` to log anything you like to the console.

Comment: Note that you probably don't want to log the private key on released builds...

Comment: So this is really an encryption question -- how do you calculate the keys from the above data (or otherwise extract them from the openSSL function).

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try is `NSLog(@"Here is my object: %@", [someobject description]);`.

`description` works, more or less, on nearly all Objective-C classes (even yours).  In some cases (the default behavior) it only displays the class name and object address, but in other cases (depending on the whim of the class developer) it rather delightfully formats the innards of the object.  It generally works well for NSArray, NSDictionary, NSData, and most other common data types.

Comment: OpenSSL is no natural objective-c framework..It is written in C..I changed my question...

Answer (score 0):

You can check t[his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613708/extracting-public-key-from-private-key-in-openssl) for some clues about how to get the key from an RSA struct.
To do you Debugging, either use an NSLog with %i instead of %@ for integers, or set a breakpoint in your callback functions and use the GDB Debugger console and it's mighty `po` command. you should be able to do things like `po rsa.e`

Comment: Thank You for answering, but I don't think the post will help me..It's for cl i think(?).I found a function RSA_print but I don't know how to use it...I changed my question.